# Why do I get a syntax error in backticks, even though it works in terminal?

Tags: linux, perl, backticks

I am trying to run a Linux command in Perl using backticks. It works when I run it directly in Linux, but when Perl does it through backticks, I get this error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
sh: -c: line 0: `(/src/storageUtil --diagnostic 2> >(tee >(cat >&2) >&1)) > log.txt'
```

The line of code in question is:

```
$output = `(/src/storageUtil --diagnostic 2> >(tee >(cat >&2) >&1)) > log.txt`;
```

Any insight as to what might cause this error would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You probably tested your code on the command line with `bash` but you're trying to run it via `sh` when you invoke it from Perl.

Comment: You are an absolute genius

Comment: I'd suggest with file redirects, you'd generally be better off `open`ing the executable for piping, and then handle the file io yourself, rather than outsourcing to shell.

Comment: @ysth: OK - comment converted to answer below now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably tested your code on the command line with `bash` but you're trying to run it via `sh` when you invoke it from Perl.

Either change your command to be compatible with the Bourne shell, or invoke `bash` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks :) you are a saviour